# Use parameter expansions in a command run from "find | xargs" to prevent output overwriting

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, xargs

I have this bash script that is looking for mp4 files in subfolders with certain names and saves frames of those videos as jpeg.

```
#!/bin/bash
find ../folder -type f -iname '*C00*.mp4' | xargs -I %% ffmpeg -i %% -vf fps=1 -q:v 3 "../frames/_${i%.*}_frame%d.jpg"
```

The problem is that everytime the script finishes one video the .jepg output files of the next videos are overwriting the existing ones.

How can I prevent that?

Comment: What sort of workaround are you looking for? Write-protecting existing files? Writing to a different location? Failing if the output file exists already?

Comment: Whatever works and is not to cmplicated would work.
I was thinking of adding a prefix number that indicates the number of the video:
e.g Video1-frame1.jpg, Video1-frame2.jpg… Video2-frame1.jpg, Video2-frame2.jpg etc..

Comment: The easiest by far is to just abort if you are about to overwrite a file, but I'm guessing if you are processing multiple videos, a separate output directory per input would be better; but I have no idea what your file names look like, so it's harder to guess what sort of output directory name we could come up with safely.

Comment: Also, what is `${id}` and `$i`?

Comment: sorry my answer came faster as wanted, please look at my edit

Comment: ${id} was a leftover a trial to insert a randomized number as variable into the filename

Comment: For background behind the several approaches to answering this question, see the "Complex Actions" and "Actions In Bulk" sections of [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick stab which creates a directory with the same name as the input file with any `.mp4` extension trimmed off.

```
#!/bin/bash
find ../folder -type f -iname '*C00*.mp4' -print0 |
xargs -r0 sh -c 'for f; do
    d="../frames/${f%.[Mm][Pp]4}"
    mkdir "$d" || { echo "$d already exists" >&2; exit 123; }
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf fps=1 -q:v 3 "$d/frame%d.jpg"
  done' _
```

Comment: ...what's the value of using `xargs` here?

Comment: Coping with complicated file names.

Comment: You get that from `find ... -exec sh -c '...' _ {} +` too, though, or just `find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do`

Comment: @triplee thanks a lot for your answer, I am running into the following errors:

    xargs: illegal option -- r
    usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
             [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
             [utility [argument ...]]

Comment: @Philipp, `-r` is a GNU `xargs` option that makes it not run the enclosed command at all if `find` had no results. If you're using a BSD xargs (like the default one on MacOS) you have that behavior by default so you can just leave out the `-r` with no ill effect.

Comment: If I wanted to save all jpegs into one folder and have a random 6 digit alphanumeric prefix for each video in the file name to prevent overwrite, how would that work?  

    eg.: 1hb4j4-frame-1.jpeg, 1hb4j4-frame-2.jpeg … 
    another video would then be 7g9x6l-frame-1.jpeg, 7g9x6l-frame-2.jpeg …

Comment: `$RANDOM` produces a random number, though it's typically five digits or less. Maybe capture two `$RANDOM` values if you need a bigger number.

Comment: thanks @triplee  how could I put this into the file name and make it unique for every video?

Comment: Try `"$d/$RANDOM%d.jpg"`as the destination filename. Maybe ask a new question if you can't figure it out.